# How to round down to nearest integer in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, rounding

How would I round down to the nearest integer in MySQL?

Example: `12345.7344 rounds to  12345`

mysql's `round()` function rounds up.

I don't know how long the values nor the decimal places will be, could be 10 digits with 4 decimal places, could be 2 digits with 7 decimal places.

Comment: You example does NOT round to the nearest integer!

Comment: @PatrickHonorez Your comment is to a 5 year old Question, and seems to have misunderstood the Question. The OP is asking for a function to round DOWN to the nearest integer.

Comment: @WarrenSergent indeed :-/

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Use [FLOOR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor):

```
SELECT FLOOR(your_field) FROM your_table
```

Comment: Ok I've deleted that comment, I did try this and it returned 0 when the `FLOOR()` was the difference between 2 subqueries (subquery difference was -70.00)...ever seen that before?

Answer (score 70):

Use [FLOOR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor).

It will to round your decimal to the **lower** integer. Examples:

```
SELECT FLOOR(1.9) /* return 1 */
SELECT FLOOR(1.1) /* return 1 */
```

#### Other useful rounding

If you want to round your decimal to the **nearest** integer, use [ROUND()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round). Examples:

```
SELECT ROUND(1.9) /* return 2 */
SELECT ROUND(1.1) /* return 1 */
```

If you want to round your decimal to the **upper** integer, use [CEILING()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceiling). Examples:

```
SELECT CEILING(1.9) /* return 2 */
SELECT CEILING(1.1) /* return 2 */
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT FLOOR(12345.7344);
```

Read more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor).

Answer (score 4):

`SUBSTR` will be better than `FLOOR` in some cases because FLOOR has a "bug" as follow:

```
SELECT 25 * 9.54 + 0.5 -> 239.00

SELECT FLOOR(25 * 9.54 + 0.5) -> 238  (oops!)

SELECT SUBSTR((25*9.54+0.5),1,LOCATE('.',(25*9.54+0.5)) - 1) -> 239
```

Comment: I just tested SELECT FLOOR(25 * 9.54 + 0.5) on MySQL 5.6.40 and it returns 239.

Answer (score 3):

The FLOOR() function will return the largest integer value that is smaller than or equal to a number.

```
example :
SELECT FLOOR(columnName) FROM tableName;
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in the following two ways:

- `select floor(desired_field_value) from table`
- `select round(desired_field_value-0.5) from table`

The 2nd-way explanation: Assume 12345.7344 integer. So, 12345.7344 - 0.5 = 12345.2344 and 
rounding off the result will be 12345.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT SUBSTR(12345.7344,1,LOCATE('.', 12345.7344) - 1)
```

or

```
SELECT FLOOR(12345.7344)
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/1897)

Answer (score 1):

if you need decimals can use this

```
DECLARE @Num NUMERIC(18, 7) = 19.1471985
SELECT FLOOR(@Num * 10000) / 10000
```

Output: 19.147100
Clear: 985
Add: 00

OR use this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Num), 1, CHARINDEX('.', @Num) + 4)
```

Output: 19.1471
Clear: 985

OR use this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, 19.99999)
```

Output: 19

this:

```
SELECT FLOOR(19.99999)
```

Output: 19

Answer (score 1):

**Both Query is used for round down the nearest integer in MySQL**

1. SELECT FLOOR(445.6) ;
2. SELECT NULL(222.456);

Comment: `FLOOR()` has already been posted as an answer. Where did you find the function `NULL()`?

Answer (score 0):

Though what have you asked is not matching with the example. But this is the answer that is more relevant to the question rather than answer:

```sql
SELECT Round(12345.7344/12345) * 12345;
```