# How can I round a number down to the nearest 10?

Tags: mysql, rounding

In MySQL I would like to round numbers down to the nearest ten.

e.g. 812 -> 810, but also 819 -> 810

Using the ROUND function does not do the trick.

Comment: (Um, this is basic arithmetic) SELECT FLOOR(812/10)*10

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361220/how-to-round-down-to-nearest-integer-in-mysql

Comment: What do you want to happen for negative inputs? E.g., what should -812 map to? -820? Or -810?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use TRUNCATE function as follow:

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(819, -1);
SELECT TRUNCATE(812, -1);

Result:
810
```

Comment: if it is multiple of 10000 then? like 15332, the output should be 10000 and if 50345 then it should be 50000...how can we achieve this?

Comment: Hi @JGS you just change -1 to -4 SELECT TRUNCATE(15332, -4);

Answer (score 9):

I would divide by 10, do a floor() then multiply by 10 to get the proper int value. So in MySQL something like that :

```
SELECT FLOOR(Myattribute / 10) * 10;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can still use the round function but specify the decimal place as a negative:

```
SELECT ROUND(812, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ["integer division" operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html), `DIV`:

```
SELECT 812 DIV 10 * 10;
```

While `TRUNCATE()` seems to be better option for "rounding" to 10, 100 etc, `DIV` can be used for "rounding" to other values as well, e.g., minutes:

```
SELECT NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() DIV 60 * 60);

+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| NOW()               | FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() DIV 60 * 60) |
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| 2020-03-17 13:51:35 | 2020-03-17 13:51:00                         |
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

In PHP I would like to round numbers down to the nearest ten.
e.g. 2013 -> 2010, but also 2019 -> 2010
The following work form me:

```
$number = 2019;
echo(round($number -5,-1) . "<br>");
```

Comment: This is helpful for PHP.  The question asks how to do this in MySQL.  To help keep answers relevant, please stick to the requested language.