# SQL Query: to show the distribution of transfer amount by interval of 10

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the table structure:
[image]

Need output in below format
[image]

Comment: Have you made any attempts at solving this tutorial/exam question yourself?

Comment: Yes @GarethD, I am able to get the count data using between queries, but not getting a breakthrough on how to increase dynamically the interval.

Comment: You should always include your attempts in the question, and explain where you have tried and failed with various parts. Just posting two screenshots with no further information is not likely to elicit a very positive response. Based on what you are stuck on, the following question should get you started - [Can I round a number down to the nearest 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631357/how-can-i-round-a-number-down-to-the-nearest-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below:

SELECT  bin, sum(amount) FROM (
SELECT TRUNCATE(transfer_amount, -1) as bin , transfer_amount as amount FROM table) Group BY bin