# Is there a ROUNDDOWN() function in sql as there is in EXCEL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, math

Say I have a table which has two columns i.e. Quantity and Percentages where my percentages are in decimals. Now I want to multiply these two columns and Round the value down to 2 decimals. Rounding down here means that all the numbers from 1-9 are rounded down. Is there an inbuilt function in SQL to do so as there is in Excel?

Examples:

```
13.567 should round to 13.56
136.7834 should round to 136.78
0.7699 should round to 0.76
```

I have tried searching for such a function online but couldn't come across an appropriate solution.

Comment: It's [all in the fantastic manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-functions.html) which is worth reading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round down to nearest integer in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361220/how-to-round-down-to-nearest-integer-in-mysql)

Comment: @MuhammadWaheed not a duplicate, as this question deals with decimal point rounding, not integers.

Comment: Thanks @CoolBots for understanding the question. The general ROUND() function round values from 0-4 as one value below and values 5-9 as one value above. The general FLOOR() function gives a value without the decimals. What I want is that say my number is 2.3456, it should be rounded to 3 decimal places as 2.345 and not 2.346.

Comment: The solution to the problem is to truncate the extra decimal which can be achieved by using the extra parameter of the ROUND function which is ROUND(number, decimal_places, 0/1). Here if the last parameter is anything other than 0, it will truncate the rather than rounding off which is equivalent to the ROUNDDOWN() function of excel that I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

There's a `FLOOR` function, which can be adapted to your use case:

```
SELECT FLOOR(value * 100) / 100 AS RoundedValue
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TRUNCATE ()` for this rounddown

```
select TRUNCATE(2.847, 2) as rounddown
```

or

```
SELECT Floor(135.675); //for integer rounding, like 135
```

You can also use

```
select round(123.456, 2, 1) as rounddown
```

The 3rd parameter being non-zero will cause a truncation after the number of decimal points specified in the 2nd parameter.

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e8a65a85294ca13080133f9d0cc7d1b1)

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_truncate.html

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_floor.asp

Comment: The OP needs to specify the number of decimal places to round down to; I don't believe `Floor` accepts such parameter

Comment: The OP was looking for a solution in MySQL, not in SqlServer. Additionally, that function does not round to two decimal places, as you can see in your fiddle

Comment: In mysql 8 it run successfully . [check it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7de2758489ced544534d683700071356)

Comment: @Shaikot I edited the question with some examples of what the result should be. Try it with those values - any mySQL version - `Floor` cannot be used to accomplish this without additional math, as per my answer.

Comment: Your ans is also return wrong ans I check it now in mysql 8. when i ans this question ,it was different. thanks for edit and clear it. then you can use TRUNCATE()

Comment: I suggested an edit for your answer, as it is now correct, but a bit unclear. I also removed my downvote. Btw , my answer returns correct results, but yours is better, as mine uses math in order to achieve what's already available via built-in functions.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem is to truncate the extra decimal which can be achieved by using the extra parameter of the ROUND function which is ROUND(number, decimal_places, 0/1). Here if the last parameter is anything other than 0, it will truncate the rather than rounding off which is equivalent to the ROUNDDOWN() function of excel that I was looking for.

Alternatively, you can use the TRUNCATE() function, passing the number of decimal places to keep as the second parameter, which will drop off any extra decimals, acting as a ROUNDDOWN() function.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this rounding utility helps somebody:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_round`(val DOUBLE, nDigits INT, RoundStyle VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS double
        NO SQL
    BEGIN
      DECLARE a DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
      SET nDigits = ifnull(nDigits, 0);

    CASE
        WHEN UCASE(RoundStyle) IN ('ROUND NEAREST','', 'NEAREST', '', 'RND','ROUND', 'DEFAULT','DFLT', null) THEN #normal rounding, but up from 10.50#
                    SET a = round(val, nDigits); 
        WHEN UCASE(RoundStyle) IN('ROUND UP', 'UP') THEN #ROUND 10.554 to 10.56
                    SET a =  ceil(val * (power(10, nDigits) )) / (power(10, nDigits));
        WHEN UCASE(RoundStyle) IN('ROUND DOWN', 'DOWN') THEN #ROUND 10.555 to 10.55
                    SET a =  truncate(val, nDigits) ;                 
        WHEN UCASE(RoundStyle) IN('ROUND BANKER', 'BANKER','BANKERS ROUNDING') THEN #ROUND TO THE NEAREST EVEN 10.555 is 10.56 and 10.565 is 10.56
                    SET a = IF(ABS(val - TRUNCATE(val, nDigits)) * POWER(10, nDigits + 1) = 5 
                            AND NOT CONVERT(TRUNCATE(ABS(val) * POWER(10, nDigits), 0), UNSIGNED) % 2 = 1,
                            TRUNCATE(val, nDigits), ROUND(val, nDigits));
        WHEN UCASE(RoundStyle) IN('ROUND UP INTEGER', 'INT UP','UP INT') THEN #10.4 rounds to 11.0
                    SET a =  ceiling(val);
        WHEN UCASE(RoundStyle) IN('ROUND DOWN INTEGER', 'INT DOWN','DOWN INT') THEN #10.6 rounds to 10.0
                    SET a =  floor(val);
    END CASE;

    RETURN ifnull(a, 0);
    END
```

Answer (score -1):

Highlight the Column in Table or Query

Go to Property Sheet

Format set to "Fixed"

Decimal Places set to "2"

This will Round the values down for the attribute.

Comment: Are you referring to some IDE for MySQL?

Answer (score -3):

yes there are some Function in sql for round

ex:

```
SELECT ProductName, Price, FlOOR(Price) AS RoundedPrice
    FROM Products;
```

Comment: Try to use hyperlinks instead of direct links

Comment: That doesn't round *down*, it just rounds - [try it](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_round)

Comment: use 0 instade of 2 [check it](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_round)

Comment: Do you understand "round down"?  0 just rounds it to zero *decimal points* - try `ROUND(135.6, 0)` - what do you get? 136, right? Not what the OP is asking.